# Is there a Unix/Linux platform equivalent to Telligent Community?

Tags: linux, unix, community

[Telligent Community](http://telligent.com/products/telligent_community/) combines blogs, wikis, forums, and file-sharing capabilities into a single product with single sign-on, using all Microsoft technologies.  Is there an equivalent offering that runs on Unix/Linux?  Or would I have to pick and choose individual product offerings and figure out another option for single sign-on across them?  Are there plug-ins for something like WordPress or MovableType that might add the necessary functionality?

A friend of mine is looking to add a "members-only" area to her company's website, and since they're hosted on Dreamhost (and can't afford [StackExchange pricing](http://stackexchange.com/pricing) yet), I'm trying to find other options for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) has everything you need available.

Other than that, the only thing that springs to mind is trawling through the [Wikipedia list of content management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems) and seeing if any take your fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility worth exploring is [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).